# How to iterate through json array in another array in android

Tags: android, json

I'm having issues consuming a web service, below is how the service looks like.

```
[

 {"NND (Megastore \/ Supermarket)":
        [
            {"question":"\"33\" Export (Can)","questionid":"32"},
            {"question":"Ace Roots (Can)","questionid":"33"},
            {"question":"Amstel (Can)","questionid":"34"},
            {"question":"Climax (Can)","questionid":"35"},
            {"question":"Fayrouz (Cann)","questionid":"36"},
            {"question":"Goldberg (RGB)","questionid":"37"},
            {"question":"Gulder (Can)","questionid":"38"},
            {"question":"Gulder  (RGB)","questionid":"39"},
            {"question":"Heineken (Can)","questionid":"40"},
            {"question":"Heineken (RGB)","questionid":"41"},
            {"question":"Legend  (Can)","questionid":"42"},
            {"question":"Maltina   (Can)","questionid":"43"},
            {"question":"Star (Can)","questionid":"44"},
            {"question":"Star (RGB)","questionid":"45"},
            {"question":"Star  Radler (Can)","questionid":"46"},
            {"question":"Strongbow (Can)","questionid":"47"}
        ]
    },

    {"NND (Superette - including returnable)":
        [
            {"question":"\"33\" Export (Can)","questionid":"48"},
            {"question":"Ace Roots (Can)","questionid":"49"},
            {"question":"Amstel (Can)","questionid":"50"},
            {"question":"Climax (Can)","questionid":"51"},
            {"question":"Fayrouz (Cann)","questionid":"52"},
            {"question":"Goldberg (RGB)","questionid":"53"},
            {"question":"Gulder (Can)","questionid":"54"},
            {"question":"Gulder  (RGB)","questionid":"55"},
            {"question":"Heineken (Can)","questionid":"56"},
            {"question":"Heineken (RGB)","questionid":"57"},
            {"question":"Legend  (Can)","questionid":"58"},
            {"question":"Maltina   (Can)","questionid":"59"},
            {"question":"Star (Can)","questionid":"60"},
            {"question":"Star (RGB)","questionid":"61"},
            {"question":"Star  Radler (Can)","questionid":"62"},
            {"question":"Strongbow (Can)","questionid":"63"}
        ]
    },
]
```

Here is the declaration of HEADER1

```
private static final String HEADER1 = "NND (Megastore \\/ Supermarket)";
```

I'm using asynctask in android, below is how my doInBackgroud code looks like.

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

        //get JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jsonParser.getMTOQuestions(mtoURL);
        //JSONObject json = jsonParser.getMTOQuestions(mtoURL);


            try{
                //JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(HEADER1);
                //JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(0);

                for(int i =0; i<json.length(); i++){
                    //Log.e("INSIDE_MTO",""+c.getString(HEADER1));
                    //String question = c.getString(QUESTION);
                    JSONObject job = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray header1 = job.getJSONArray(HEADER1);
                    listDataHeader.add(HEADER1);
                    Log.e("INSIDE_MTO",""+json);
                    for (int quest_in_headr = 0; quest_in_headr<header1.length(); quest_in_headr++){
                        JSONObject jsonHeader1 = header1.getJSONObject(quest_in_headr);
                        question = jsonHeader1.getString(QUESTION);
                        String qid = jsonHeader1.getString(QUESTION_ID);
                        //HashMap<String, String> forHeader1 = new HashMap<>();
                        List<String> forHeader1 = new ArrayList<>();
                        forHeader1.add(question.trim());
                        //Log.e("INSIDE_INNER_LOOP", question);
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), forHeader1);
                        //Log.e("ADD_DATA",""+listDataHeader.add(HEADER1));
                    }

                    // map.put(QUESTION_ID, qid.trim());

                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {

            }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is how JSONParser code looks like

```
   public JSONArray getMTOQuestions(String url){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line);
                //Log.i("OutletList",line+"\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e("MTOQUESTION","Failed load MTO questionnaire");
        }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException cpe){
        cpe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioexception){
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

    }

    //try parse the JSON to an Object
    try{
        jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString().trim());
    }
    catch (JSONException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    //return the JSON string gotten
    return jarray;
}
```

what Log.e("INSIDE_MTO",""+json); returns is

```
[{"NND (Megastore \/ Supermarket)":[{"question":"\"33\" Export (Can)","questionid":"32"},{"question":"Ace Roots (Can)","questionid":"33"},{"question":"Amstel (Can)","questionid":"34"},{"question":"Climax (Can)","questionid":"35"},{"question":"Fayrouz (Cann)","questionid":"36"},{"question":"Goldberg (RGB)","questionid":"37"},{"question":"Gulder (Can)","questionid":"38"},{"question":"Gulder  (RGB)","questionid":"39"},{"question":"Heineken (Can)","questionid":"40"},{"question":"Heineken (RGB)","questionid":"41"},{"question":"Legend  (Can)","questionid":"42"},{"question":"Maltina   (Can)","questionid":"43"},{"question":"Star (Can)","questionid":"44"},{"question":"Star (RGB)","questionid":"45"},{"question":"Star  Radler (Can)","questionid":"46"},{"question":"Strongbow (Can)","questionid":"47"}]},{"NND (Superette - including returnable)":[{"question":"\"33\" Export (Can)","questionid":"48"},{"question":"Ace Roots (Can)","questionid":"49"},{"question":"Amstel (Can)","questionid":"50"},{"question":"Climax (Can)","questionid":"51"},{"question":"Fayrouz (Cann)","questionid":"52"},{"question":"Goldberg (RGB)","questionid":"53"},{"question":"Gulder (Can)","questionid":"54"},{"question":"Gulder  (RGB)","questionid":"55"},{"question":"Heineken (Can)","questionid":"56"},{"question":"Heineken (RGB)","questionid":"57"},{"question":"Legend  (Can)","questionid":"58"},{"question":"Maltina   (Can)","questionid":"59"},{"question":"Star (Can)","questionid":"60"},{"question":"Star (RGB)","questionid":"61"},{"question":"Star  Radler (Can)","questionid":"62"},{"question":"Strongbow (Can)","questionid":"63"}]}]
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
JsonException "org.json.JSONException: No value for  NND (Megastore \/ Supermarket)"
```

and the error is pointing to this line of code

```
JSONArray header1 = job.getJSONArray(HEADER1);
```

I've searched online and saw similar question here on Stackoverflow but it seems my own case is a bit different. I'll appreciate you guys if you could help out.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve]. For example, we can't help you without the value of `HEADER1` and your JSON (and code) can be significantly reduced to only highlight the problem

Comment: Though, I think the problem is that if `HEADER1` is `NND (Megastore \/ Supermarket)`, then your second JSON object in the array doesn't have that header, so of course you get that exception

Comment: @cricket_007 here is the value of HEADER1
NND (Megastore \/ Supermarket)
I've also updated the question to show what Log.e("INSIDE_MTO",""+json); returns

Comment: Double check that you don't have extra blank spaces in the value of HEADER1.

Comment: Please edit your question again with the actual Java code that assigns the value of `HEADER1`

Comment: @cricket_007 this has been done.

Comment: Please see the second comment here...

Comment: @dev.bmax, I've confirmed that by using replace to remove extra space
private static final String HEADER1 = "NND (Megastore \\/ Supermarket)".replace("\"", "");

Comment: I think that @cricket_007 has found the problem. You should store all headers in an array and use a different header in each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @dev.bmax thank you for your suggestion, I've been able to loop through the keys in the array and then use result to loop through the arrays in the keys. I'm fine now.

Comment: Please post your own answer. Don't edit my post

Comment: That's not a problem, I'll do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated code and it's working as expected. So what I did was to get the JSON then get the keys with variable obj then loop through the keys to get the arrays inside the keys.

```
 JSONArray json = jsonParser.getMTOQuestions(mtoURL);


        try {
            //JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(HEADER1);
            //JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                //Log.e("INSIDE_MTO",""+c.getString(HEADER1));
                //String question = c.getString(QUESTION);
                JSONObject job = json.getJSONObject(i);
                Iterator<?> keys = job.keys();
                //int child = 0;
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) keys.next();
                    try {
                        Log.e("INSIDE_MTO", "" + key);
                        listDataHeader.add(key);

                        JSONArray headers = job.getJSONArray(key);
                        List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int quest_in_headr = 0; quest_in_headr < headers.length(); quest_in_headr++) {
                            JSONObject jsonHeader1 = headers.getJSONObject(quest_in_headr);
                            question = jsonHeader1.getString(QUESTION);
                            qid = jsonHeader1.getString(QUESTION_ID);

                            questionList.add(question.trim());
                            //Log.e("INSIDE_INNER_LOOP", question + " " + qid);
                            //Log.e("ADD_DATA", "" + question);
                        }
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), questionList);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("VALUES_IN_QUESTANS", "" + questans);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: that wasn't intentional, it was because I wanted the other people to know that the updated code is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

The object of `{"NND (Superette - including returnable)":` is throwing the exception.

The first JSON Object that has the correct key of the `HEADER1` value is not the problem.

You are parsing that second (and subsequent) JSON object with this code

```
for(int i =0; i<json.length(); i++){
    JSONObject job = json.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray header1 = job.getJSONArray(HEADER1); // Error when i >= 1
```